# Display -1 Overflowing jumbotron (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am very new to bootstrap, and I am working on a website to get a feel for it.
I made a `<div class="jumbotron>"` and put a heading into it. However, the standard heading looked too small, so I replaced it with a `display-1` heading from bootstrap. However, when I viewed the page on a phone, the text overflowed out of the jumbotron. I am not really sure why this happened. I can fix it by making the text smaller, but that makes it look really tiny on a desktop. Essentially what I want is for the text to look big on desktops, but be properly formatted on mobile devices.  Below are some screenshots:
[image: How the sites looks normally]

[image: Smaller screen]

And here is my code:
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
//require statements for data that belongs in head
require "include/head-data.html";
?>
<title>Gift Exchange</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="jumbotron text-danger border border-primary"><h1 class="display-1">Gift Exchange</h1></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 pb-3 bg-secondary text-important">
    <h2><abbr>Navigation</abbr></h2>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success border-light" role="button">Home</a>
    <a href="account_creation.php" class="btn btn-primary border border-light" role="button">Login / Create Account</a>
    <a href="about.php" class="btn btn-primary border border-light" role="button">About</a>
    <a href="help.php" class="btn btn-primary border border-light" role="button">Help</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 bg-primary text-body">
    <h1>Welcome to Gift Exchange!</h1>
    <p>Gift Exchange is a website which allows you to connect with your friends and family. You can ask for a gift, and give others gifts. Gift exchange takes the guesswork out of giving, making sure that at the end of the day, everyone is happy. Learn more about Gift Exchange at the 'About This Site' page.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my head-data.html (which is included via the php require statement)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My server apache2, and is located my local machine

I use the brave browser

My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04

The included screenshot of the 'smaller screen' was taken using the dev tools, but the issue looked the same when I viewed it on my actual phone.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class and add your custom CSS in it and define font-size that you want to apply. then use bootstrap media quires to make it responsive on each device by just simply adding that previous class you just created in media query and then change its font-size to your desired value. Example is here below...

```
.custom-heading{ font-size:2rem; }
```

Then create media query /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { .custom-heading{ font-size:1rem; } }
```

also sharing reference link below.

[bootstrap media queries](https://bootstrapcreative.com/bootstrap-4-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `display-1` and add css to that html, like this

```
<h1 style="font-size: 300%;">Gift Exchange</h1>
```

adjust the percentage according to the requirement.

The size is given in percentages because,  the size changes with width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap Sass, you can enable [Responsive Font Sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) feature by changing the `$enable-responsive-font-sizes` Sass variable to `true`.

You can check out the demo for display headings after turning Responsive Font Sizes feature on here at https://project-rfs.github.io/docs/4.3/content/typography/#display-headings